# How to use async servlet + non blocking IO for file download?

Tags: io, java-ee-7, servlet-3.1

My image files are stored in database (I know they shouldn't be, but can't help).
To be able to render them on clients, I've implemented an async servlet that helps read the binary stream off the database column and write on to the Output Stream of Servlet Response. Traditional IO works just fine here.

When I thought of trying the non blocking IO with async servlet (to test performance), my binary data returned in the response keeps getting corrupted.

Starting with the [Oracle Blog](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HTML5andServlet31/HTML5andServlet%203.1.html), I've seen various examples of file upload with async NIO servlet, but no help with my issue.

Here's the servlet code:

```
@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = "/myDownloadServlet")
public class FileRetrievalServletAsyncNIO extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6914766655133758332L;

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Queue<byte[]> containerQueue = new LinkedList<byte[]>();

        AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync();
        asyncContext.addListener(new AsyncListenerImpl());
        asyncContext.setTimeout(120000);

        try
        {
            long attachmentId = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));
            MyAttachmentDataObject retObj = ServletUtils.fetchAttachmentHeaders(attachmentId);

            response = (HttpServletResponse) asyncContext.getResponse();
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(retObj.getContentLength()));
            if (Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter(ServletConstants.REQ_PARAM_ENABLE_DOWNLOAD)))
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + retObj.getName());
            response.setContentType(retObj.getContentType());
            ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
            ServletUtils.fetchContentStreamInChunks(attachmentId, containerQueue); // reads from database and adds to the queue in chunks
            sos.setWriteListener(new WriteListenerImpl(sos, containerQueue, asyncContext));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException | IOException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            request.setAttribute("message", "Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the write listener implementation

```
public class WriteListenerImpl implements WriteListener
{

    private ServletOutputStream output = null;
    private Queue<byte[]> queue = null;
    private AsyncContext asyncContext = null;
    private HttpServletRequest request = null;
    private HttpServletResponse response = null;

    public WriteListenerImpl(ServletOutputStream sos, Queue<byte[]> q, AsyncContext aCtx)
    {
        output = sos;
        queue = q;
        asyncContext = aCtx;
        request = (HttpServletRequest) asyncContext.getRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWritePossible() throws IOException
    {
        while(output.isReady())
        {
            while (!queue.isEmpty())
            {
                byte[] temp = queue.poll();
                output.write(temp, 0, temp.length);
            }

            asyncContext.complete();
            request.setAttribute("message", "Success");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t)
    {
        System.err.println(t);
        try
        {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        catch (IOException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        request.setAttribute("message", "Failure");
        asyncContext.complete();
    }
}
```

The response data looks like this:

[image: Response Data]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you expect the output to look like but in terms of async i/o you should check output.isReady() before every write. So your onWritePossible code should be:

```
while(output.isReady() && !queue.isEmpty())
 {
       byte[] temp = queue.poll();
       output.write(temp, 0, temp.length);
 }

 if (queue.isEmpty()) {
      asyncContext.complete();
      request.setAttribute("message", "Success");
 }
```

This allows onWritePossible() to return if writing becomes blocked which is the basically the point of async I/O.

If you write when writing is blocked (output.isReady() would return false) different implementations may either ignore the write or throw an exception.  Either way your output data would be either missing some writes in the middle or truncated.

Comment: Nope that didn't work. The downloaded file is improper.

Comment: what is the problem with the file? and how did you previously write in the file before you tried using async io?

Comment: There's no problem with the file. Download is working perfectly with async servlet + traditional IO. It's only the NIO that's not working for some reason.

Comment: What is the issue with the download? Also, if you change your code so that the servlet loops through the data and writes the day out without using a writeListener does it work OK then?

Comment: Yes, without write listener everything works. Also, there are some minute differences between servlet implementations of Wildfly and Tomcat. Still not sure of the problem. Have to dig deeper I guess.